# ShellExecuteEx returning 42 in hInstApp when expecting a 31 (No file association)

Tags: delphi, shellexecuteex

When using ShellExecuteEx in Delphi 7 to open a file using a verb, I always seem to be getting 42 back as a result in hInstApp, even though I'm expecting to get a failure and a 31 result, as there is no file association. I am moving from ShellExecute, to ShellExecuteEx so that I can use WaitForInputIdle with the process handle.

ShellExecute returns a 31 as expected when I try to open an XLS file when I dont have Excel installed, but ShellExecuteEx appears to succeed and return 42, even though it has actually failed and popped up the default Windows file association dialog.

Am i doing something wrong? Using Delphi 7 on WinXP and Win7.

Sample code below. Using Delphi 7 on a Win XP 32 bit OS, but also getting the same results on Win 7 64 bit. Just doing a showmessage on the hInstApp value returns 42 when I would expect to get 31 as I don't have Excel installed.

```
var
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(ExecInfo, sizeof(ExecInfo));
  with ExecInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := sizeOf(ExecInfo);
    fMask  := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    lpVerb := PChar('open');
    lpFile := PChar('c:\windows\temp\test.xls');
    nShow  := 1;
  end;
  ShellExecuteEx(@ExecInfo);
  if ExecInfo.hInstApp<32
  then WaitForInputIdle(ExecInfo.hProcess, 10000);
end;
```

Comment: Without code, it's very hard to say what might be wrong. Also, it might make a difference which version of Windows you're running where you're having this problem.

Comment: Do you have an advertised Excel installation?

Comment: I would first make sure that ShellExecuteEx returns TRUE before investigating any further.

Comment: It does indeed return TRUE, which is confusing me as it plainly hasn't succeeded.

Comment: In order to diagnose this, you should be concentrating on the file association angle rather than the Delphi code. Clearly this is a local configuration issue.

Comment: If that is the case, then I don't understand why it works fine using ShellExecute. This is some legacy code that I'm working on and its never been a problem when using ShellExecute, it always returns a 31 error code when there is no file association.

Comment: Always checking return values from API calls is a thing to concentrate on too.

Comment: Also, logic is inverted, succeed := hInstApp > 32

Answer (score 1):

ShelLExecuteEx return values are not the same as ShelLExecute. Read the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=VS.85%29.aspx. Also check you have set the proper flags in SHELLEXECUTEINFO for the proper behaviour when an error occurs.

Comment: I first though the return values were different, but that page would suggest not. It says the hInstApp values are the same for ShellExecute and ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: What if yo set SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI?

Answer (score 0):

The function ZeroMemory should be called with a pointer as parameter:

```
ZeroMemory(@ExecInfo, sizeof(ExecInfo));
```

Then i would use the result of Shell ExecuteEx to proceed:

```
if (ShellExecuteEx(@ExecInfo)) then
```

As far as i know you should close the handle in the end:

```
CloseHandle(ExecInfo.hProcess);
```

Calling the function with the verb set to nil, will tell Windows to use the standard verb, it is a bit more generic than 'open'.

I made an [example](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#AppStart) to wait on an application to end, but you could easily replace WaitForSingleObject with WaitForInputIdle.

Answer (score 0):

Nehpets: "it plainly hasn't succeeded".
Actually, it has: it successfully ran RunDll32.Exe.

Make sure the fMask member contains SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT.
If it doesn't. you may see the "Open With" dialog.